# Would certain defective clones have the inhibitor chip?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, clones

This question has bothered me since I learned about the [Bad Batch](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Clone_Force_99). They are a group of positively defective clone commandos. Were they defective enough to not have an inhibitor chip placed in them at birth? The same goes for the clone 99. Also, with the big explosion that Echo was in, do you think that he would still have a working inhibitor chip?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Probably

The Bad Batch was designed as part of Kaminoan experiments in creating super-soldiers. According to the [Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/clone-force-99-bad-batch):

> During the creation of the clone army, the Kaminoans made genetic
>   experiments in an attempt to create super soldiers. While the plan
>   never quite worked, four of those experiments came to form Clone Force
>   99, or, as they called themselves, the Bad Batch.

As such, they, more than any other clones, would need inhibitor chips to ensure compliance. It seems almost certain that (as with any other clones that were intended to serve in combat), the Bad Batch were implanted with inhibitor chips.

Similarly for the [clone](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/99) that the unit was named after. He seems to have been an ordinary clone for whom the cloning process went wrong. He probably would also have been implanted with an inhibitor chip.

As for Echo, let’s keep in mind that these inhibitor chips were designed for an army of millions of clone troopers—in other words, soldiers. They were *expected* to encounter explosions, blasters, missiles, slugthrowers, and various other lethal situations. It seems unlikely that this sort of trauma would reliably disable the inhibitor chip, given that a large percentage of the clones could be reliably assumed to have encountered similarly severe physical trauma.

Comment: did 99 have the chip?

Comment: Now confirmed in the first episode of the Bad Batch show, they all had chips, but their divergence from normal clones caused them to be ineffective. Echo's chip was disabled by his cyborg mods.